# W A S D keys are swapped with arrow keys?

Tags: windows-7

I have a desktop that I don't use that much (mostly for burning CD's and stuff). I logged on and wanted to search for a program only to realize that the <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> keys are swapped with the arrow keys. For example: If I'm in Notepad, and I press the Left Arrow key, it's going to type 'D'. If I press the <kbd>D</kbd> key, it's going to scroll right and whatnot.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is your keyboard layout DVORAK? If it is, try changing the setting to QWERTY

Comment: @Prasanna [This is my keyboard](http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server4600/8e755/products/75628/images/65164/29%2540MKA-7-855x600px__82169.1409264505.1280.1280.jpg?c=2). I don't understand what you mean by Dvorak xD

Comment: look for a running utility? possibly in the notification area (systray) or as seen in the run (registry) or startup, could use hijackthis or autoruns to find running/starting programs/utilities easier. Check control pannel / keyboard , if some utility or driver has a property sheet (tab) added there for the feature?

Comment: @Prasanna : Aidan, then check out [Wikipedia on Dvorak Simplified Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) to learn that it is another keyboard layout.  Oh, you added xD, presumably a silly version of a smiley face.  Maybe I should go check the image pointed to by the hyperlink you provided. Oh, that's an error 404.  Well, that wasn't very resilient to link rot.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, usually on the right side of the space bar, and press <kbd>W</kbd> while you are holding it. Should fix it instantly. (And you can swap between them any time.)

Comment: worked for me with a RedDragon keyboard

Comment: Working on Digital Alliance Gaming keyboard too

Comment: With my Ozone strike pro, the shortcut is (once in gaming mode) `Ozone key` + `left window`.  
If `Fn`+`W` do not work (or you don't have an `Fn` key), simply read your keyboard's manual

Comment: I accidentally pressed those keys and had no idea of what was happening. Thank you.

Comment: My cat rested on the keyboard and this helped me out. It's an unbranded gaming keyboard.

Comment: Huh. Okay, but why??

Comment: For some reason, I had to hold down W first, and then hit the Fn key. Redragon keyboard. I really want to turn this "feature" off. Messes everything up!

Answer (score 8):

Hold **FN** (function) and Then Press **W** And I should Fix it :D

Comment: So, this answer has -1 votes (as of writing this), while the most voted answer, with 4 votes, is *exactly the same*. Can anyone explain the disparity? Is it because the *new* user did not read the previous answers before posting, or there is something else to it?

Comment: @ysap I didn't downvote, but repeating old answers isn't useful, and that's exactly what the tooltip on the downvote button says.

Comment: Repeating the same information isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I fixed by unplugging my keyboard and plugging it back in again.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key while holding, and it was fixed instantly.

Comment: (1) An anonymous user [edited this answer,](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1078124) totally changing the meaning.  We generally do not allow such drastic edits, especially from anonymous users.  If you (anonymous user) believe that this answer is wrong, log in (creating an account first, if necessary), post a comment (earning 50 reputation first, if necessary), and post an answer containing the correct information.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) The edit had a comment that said “fn is the/a key on a Mac keyboard”.  If you don’t know that many keyboards have an <Fn> key, not just Mac, then you probably shouldn’t be tampering with posts about keystrokes (keyboard shortcuts) for Windows. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … By the way, the original author of this answer seems to have retired from Stack Exchange, so we can’t wait for him to verify that he wrote what he meant to write.

Comment: I deleted a popular years-old question because random editors were drastically changing the meaning of the question, presumably to pick up a few points here or there for "helpfully" "updating" an older post. I was tired of having to revert edits and recontextualize the question on a weekly basis so I deleted the question. Think before you edit; it's no wonder that people "retire" from the SO community...