# is there a standard way to turn on wasd arrow key option for windows 7/10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a standard way to turn on  wasd arrow key option for windows 7/10?  I was surprised to discover that it isn't easy to find an answer to this question.

Comment: I have not seen this before. Try the Fn Left Arrow key . I saw this confirmed here:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/wasd-keys-switched-with-arrow-keys-keyboard/d1ae6ad8-b04a-4f42-88da-403f3f0c9352

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1025357/40928

Answer (score 4):

You need a third-party keyboard remapping product such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

For example,
the following AutoHotkey script will map `wasd` to arrow keys when
CapsLock is toggled on:

```
#If GetKeyState("Capslock","T")
w::up
s::down
a::left
d::right
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group.

Answer (score 0):

For VIM style (hjkl):

```
#If GetKeyState("Capslock","T")
k::up
j::down
h::left
l::right
#If
```